# Add custom attributes to AWS ECS resource with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to add [custom attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html#attributes) to ECS resources; i.e., I want to do the equivalent of the AWS CLI command [aws ecs put-attributes](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/put-attributes.html). However, I haven't found documentation on how to do that. Is it possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is for ECS and not Fargate?

Comment: @MarkoE I'm specifically concerned with a Fargate container atm, but the Terraform resources are for ECS. I'm new to AWS, apologies if I'm muddling things.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done for Fargate though: `For tasks that use the EC2 launch type, you can use constraints to place tasks based on Availability Zone, instance type, or custom attributes. `. Here is the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#constraints.

Comment: OK. Regardless of whether or not it can be done for Fargate, you can do it for ECS resources in-general. See documentation here re using attributes for task placement constraints: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html

Comment: You can do that with the existing attributes in terraform, however I don't think it's possible to create custom ones using it. What you could do is run the AWS CLI command using the `null_resource`.